# How can I extract a text before or after specific character in SQL

Tags: sql, string, text, trim

How can I extract a text before or after specific character in SQL.

Friday|10:30-21:00
Friday|6:00-21:00
Monday|10:30-21:00
Saturday|10:00-2:00

I want to extract after | character.

Thanks,

Comment: When you copy/paste this post title into a search engine, does anything useful come up?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use string manipulation functions. Consider:

`SELECT *, Mid(fieldname, InStr(fieldname, "|")+1) AS NewData FROM tablename`

Answer (score 0):

This us easy with `charindex` and `stuff`, depending on your database, syntax might vary.

```
select Stuff(column,1,CharIndex('|',column),'')
from Yourtable
```